# Calculate median and average in a partition in Tableau using table calculation

Tags: tableau-api

I have a details table of posts and subjects digged from a forum. Row is the single subject (ie postID and subjectIS is the primary key for the table), then I have some measures at subject level and some at post level. For example:

```
    +---------+-------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------+
    | post.ID | post.Author | post.Replies | subject.ID | subject.Rank | year   |
    +---------+-------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------+
    |   1     |   mike      |     10       |    movie   |     4        |  1990  |
    |   1     |   mike      |     10       |    comics  |     6        |  1990  |
    |   2     |   sarah     |      0       |    tv      |    10        |  2001  |
    |   3     |   tom       |      4       |    tv      |    10        |  2003  |
    |   3     |   tom       |      4       |    comics  |     6        |  2003  |
    |   4     |   mike      |      1       |    movie   |     4        |  2008  |
    +---------+-------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------+
```

I want to study the trend of posts and subjects by year and color it by `subject.Rank`.

Firsts are easily measured putting COUNTD(post.ID) and COUNTD(subject.ID) in rows and 'year' in column.
But if I drag MEDIAN(subject.Rank) in Color, I got a wrong result: it's not calculated at distinct subject.ID level but at row level.

I think I can accomplish it using table calculation features, but I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Problem is you may have many "duplicates" of the same subject, and want to consider each only once. There might be a way to calculate this directly from that data source, but I can't think of any right now. What I would do is to create a new table, very simple, with subject.ID and subject.Rank, with no duplicates. Then connect to that table (and join, or use data blending) and use it to calculate the median.

Comment: Tnx @Inox for your comment; I know I can handle it from the Back-End side, there're many different way to accomplish it with a simple ETL (using PL/SQL Window, for example) or even a simpler Excel file. But I was wondering of a pure Tableau solution, this time.

Comment: Well, you can do everything I said on Tableau =D. Just create a view with subject.ID and subject.Rank, export it to an Excel or mdb or csv, connect to it, then blend on subject.ID. Not optimal, not smart, but doable. The problem is that you have "duplicated" values, and the aggregation you want to use is MEDIAN. If it were SUM or AVERAGE, I could think of some way to weighting the values to get the right contribution, but Median works differently.

Comment: By the way, median of rank is a rather odd concept. But if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to treat Subject.Rank as a dimension, instead of as a measure. If so, just convert it to a dimension on the worksheet in question by right clicking on the field and choosing dimension. You can also convert it to a dimension in the data pane by dragging the field from the measures section up to the dimensions section. That will tell Tableau to treat that field as a dimension by default in the future.

A field can be treated a dimension in some cases, and a measure in others. Depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are familiar with SQL, dimensions are used to partition data rows for aggregation using the GROUP BY clause.

Finally, count distinct (COUNTD) can be expensive on large datasets. Often, you can get the same result another way. So try to think of other approaches and save COUNTD for when you really need it.

Comment: I don't believe that it will help OP with the problem of "duplicated values"

Comment: Treating subject.rank as dimension will partition the data by subject and allow him to separate whatever measures he requests into different blocks according to their subject.rank. That will let him color by each subject.rank as requested. Whether or not count distinct is necessary or makes senses for his measures is a different question -- and kind of hard to tell from the question text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using {fixed [1st LEVEL],[2nd level]: median()}
or 
Table calculation approach
when you put in median there is an edit table calculation under advance compute using put you fields in there(Make sure its ordered the way you want it to calculate when you select them) then click OK select the at which level and restart every